# How to return a string to the Swift view that called the current objective-c view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I start in View1 which uses swift, I call View2 which is in objective-c, I gather input in View2 and I want to return a String to View1.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: You will need a bridging header so that the objective-c view can reference the swift view. Then you can use the normal methods (notification, reference to the view, etc) to pass the string.

Comment: @keithbhunter xcode made the header for me. I am in iOS n00b. Could you step me through with a little more detail please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setup your Swift files to reference Objective-C code:

1. `#import` the Objective-C header files you want to use in Swift (`ViewController2.h`) into
   the auto-generated `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h`. Also import any
   frameworks that the imported files rely on.

Setup your Objective-C files to reference Swift code:

1. In your build settings:

   - Set `Embedded Content Conatins Swift Code` to `Yes`
   - Set `Install Objective-C Compatibility Header` to `Yes`
   - Get the file name from `Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name`. This will look like `ProjectName-Swift.h`
2. In your Swift class, add `@objc` as follows:

   - `@objc class ViewController1: UIViewController { ... }`
3. In `ViewController2.m` or `.h`, `#import "ProjectName-Swift.h`. This may or may not autocomplete for you, so type it out.

Now you are setup to reference the view controllers in the different languages. Let's assume that `ViewController1` is the parent view controller to `ViewController2`. You can now pass the string back like so:

```
NSString *input = // get the input
ViewConrtoller1 *viewContr1 = (ViewConrtoller1 *)self.parentViewController;
viewContr1.stringInput = input;
```

Or going from `ViewController1` to `ViewController2`:

```
// in prepare for segue
let someString = // whatever you want to pass
let viewContr2 = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2
viewController2.someString = someString
```

Comment: Looks good. However, how could I do this using delegation?

Comment: Declare the delegate protocol in `ViewController2` and make a `delegate` property on `ViewController2` that conforms to the protocol. Then when you want to notify the delegate of any changes, do the normal `[self.delegate notifyOfInput:input]`. Bouncing between Swift and Objective-C is not a big deal; the syntax changes, but the concepts are the similar.